# How can you cancel your whole Discord Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm creating a Discord Application bot, Ban appeal Application that works within DM's only. I type the command `p!apply` and start the application, however whenever I try to cancel the application by typing `cancel` it only replies and does not actually cancel the whole form.

Here's my code:

```
let userApplications = {}


client.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.equals(client.user)) return;
  
    let authorId = message.author.id;
  
    if (message.content === prefix + "apply") {
        if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
            userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}
  
            message.author.send("**__Team PhyZics Discord Ban Appeal Form__** \n  If you're applying to get unbanned from our server, please fill this application out. We do not accept all applications, so take this application seriously and take your time when filling this out. \n \n - If you want to cancel this application please type `cancel`");
            message.author.send("**Question 1: Which server did you get banned from?**");
        }
  
    } else {
  
        if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
            if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
                return message.author.send('Application Cancelled');
                
               
            }
            let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];
  
            if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
                authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
                message.author.send("**Question 2: Why did you get banned/What reason did you get banned for?**");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
                authorApplication.answer2 = message.content;
                message.author.send("**Question 3: Why do you want to get unbanned?**");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
                authorApplication.answer3 = message.content;
                message.author.send("**Question 4: Any questions or concerns? If not, please type `no`.**");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
  
            else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
                authorApplication.answer4 = message.content;
                message.author.send("Your application has been submitted, please be patient and do not ask any staff member regarding to your ban appeal.");
                client.channels.cache.get("790376360848785419")
                  .send(`**${message.author.tag}'s Application** \n **Q1**: ${authorApplication.answer1} \n **Q2:** ${authorApplication.answer2} \n **Q3:** ${authorApplication.answer3} \n **Q4:** ${authorApplication.answer4} `);
                delete userApplications[authorId];
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxUYD.png)

Comment: What does it reply with? Can you provide some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: Sure https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/732388994595291189/790593939961937951/unknown.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this problem because you're only returning a message `Application cancelled` without actually removing the user from your `userApplications` object.

To fix this, all you have to do is delete the entry from your object when the user cancels, like so:

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'cancel') {
    delete userApplications[authorId];

    return message.author.send('Application Cancelled');
}
```